# How to resample audio on-the-fly with sox

Tags: linux, raspbian, sox

If you answer I'll give you a cookie!

I am using `sox` to convert MP3 files to a WAV on the fly for `pifm`. The only thing is, I am doing it to a whole directory of MP3s, and because not all of them have the same sample rate the command fails.

Is there a way to resample the audio files, pipe it into the *convert-to-wav-on-the-fly*, and then pipe it into `pifm`?

My current command is:

```
sox -t mp3 /home/pi/Desktop/music/*.mp3 -t wav - |
sudo ./pi_fm_rds -freq 94.5  -audio - -ps ZSFM -rt ZSFM
```

But this gives me:

```
sox WARN mp3-util: MAD lost sync
sox WARN mp3-util: MAD lost sync
sox FAIL sox: Input files must have the same sample-rate
```

So I want to have sox resample each file on the fly, then pipe it into sox to convert it on the fly.

Also, if I try:

```
sox -r 44100-t mp3 /home/pi/Desktop/music/*.mp3 -t wav - |
sudo ./pi_fm_rds -freq 94.5  -audio - -ps ZSFM -rt ZSFM
```

It still does not work, because the sampling rates for the files in that directory are not the same.

Comment: Not tested, but as `man sox` says, try putting the options for the outfile before the outfile: `sox -t mp3 /home/pi/Desktop/music/*.mp3 -t wav -r 44100 -`. If that doesn't work, you need an effect; the man page suggests `rate`.

Comment: @dirkt That worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one workaround you could use (assuming your files are named sensibly):

```
for tune in *.mp3; do 
  sox $tune -t wav - rate 44100
done |
sudo ./pi_fm_rds -freq 94.5  -audio - -ps ZSFM -rt ZSFM
...
```

Comment: Thanks! That also worked, but I went with the other answer because I am a linux beginner and don't totally understand how that works. I will try to look inti it now!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @dirkt and @Thor

@dirkt answered:

```
sox -t mp3 /home/pi/Desktop/music/*.mp3 -t wav -r 44100 - | sudo ./pi_fm_rds -freq 94.5  -audio - -ps ZSFM -rt ZSFM
```

@Thor answered:

```
for tune in *.mp3; do 
  sox $tune -t wav - rate 44100
done |
sudo ./pi_fm_rds -freq 94.5  -audio - -ps ZSFM -rt ZSFM
```

Both worked!